# How to maximize shipping box volume

Tags: optimization

Earlier last week I realized I needed to ship a large volume of things domestically. Of course, I decided that I wanted to do so as cheaply as possible.

I first looked at [USPS standard post rates](http://pe.usps.com/text/dmm300/Notice123.htm#1152660). I noted that if the "combined length and girth" of a box exceeds 108", then the package becomes significantly more expensive, as it uses the "oversized" price bracket, so I resolved not to exceed this size limit. The length of a box is defined as its longest dimension, and its girth is defined as the perimeter around the rectangle to which the length is orthogonal – in other words, the girth is $2w + 2h$.

However, because I have much to ship, I also would like to maximize the volume of such a box while not exceeding this limit. This turns into a maximization problem with a constraint:

Maximize $V(x) = lwh$, while satisfying $108 >= l + 2w + 2h$.

This seems pretty simple, but I'm not sure how to handle the three nominally independent variables $l$, $w$, and $h$. Because I did not want to wait or rely on my faulty math skills, I ultimately asked Wolfram|Alpha to solve this for me, yielding a box of size 36"x18"x18". This makes intuitive sense, to a degree, but I would like a hint as to how I could have proceeded to solve this on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for a hint.  Here are two.

(1) You certainly want $l+2w+2h=108$.

(2) If you temporarily fix $l$, you have a certain amount to make a rectangle with $w$ and $h$.  The maximum area would be to make a square out of $w$ and $h$ (i.e., $w=h$).

Comment: Thanks! Using this same scheme, I can get this to a one-variable maximization problem, and then it's trivial. I knew it couldn't be that hard!

Answer (score 0):

The AM/GM inequality shows immediately that the maximum volume occurs uniquely when $l=2w=2h$.